# How to use both str_wrap and reorder columns by ascending value in a geom_bar chart?

Tags: graph, charts, visualization

I have a dataframe, perc_responses_1, that looks like this:

```
Options      Percent
a_Option1      0.03
z_Option2      0.05
b_Option3      0.50
x_Option4      0.25
```

I want to create a bar chart that sorts the bars in descending value. So, the first bar would be b_Option3, the second bar would be x_Option4, and so on.

My actual rownames are very long, for example "Purchasing more land for parks and open space", so I want to use str_wrap to wrap the labels.

Here are the rownames:

```
rownames(perc_responses_1) <- c("More bike paths and hiking trails","Removal of invasive plant species","Updating buildings and facilities","Purchasing more land for parks and open space")
```

However, when I add the str_wrap argument to my ggplot function, it reorders the columns in alphabetical order. How can I both use string wrap and reorder columns by value?

This is my code, when I run this code, the bars are in alphabetical order:

```
ggplot(perc_responses_1, aes(x = reorder(Options, -Percent), Percent)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, .7))+
  aes(stringr::str_wrap(Options, 20), Percent) +
  labs(x = "Options") + theme_bw()
```

When I run this code, the bars are in the right order, but the labels are not wrapped:

```
ggplot(perc_responses_1, aes(x = reorder(Options, -Percent), Percent)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits = c(0, .7))+
  labs(x = "Options") + theme_bw()
```